# Swift (1.2) : Unable to call a generic initializer from a class with subclassing and protocol conformance

Tags: ios, swift, generics, initialization

I'm trying to initialize a Generic for classes with subclassing and protocol conformance, but i'm unable to do it, XCode is not happy with it.

Here's a simpler (tested) example of my code :

```
import Foundation

// Definition of my protocol, adding a required initializer to a class
public protocol Protocol {
  init(foo:Int, bar:Int)
}

// This is a much simpler class supposed to represent the Realm Object base class
// making it possible to reproduce the problem
// To be more accurate, you can import RealmSwift and replace it with Object
// but actually the problem can be reproduce with any class with subclassing
class FakeRealmObject: NSObject {
  // Object stuff
}

// This is my class subclassing the Realm Object, defining a data model
final class Model: FakeRealmObject {
  // Model stuff
}

// This is the extension of my class Model, conforming to my protocol Protocol 
// This is the initializer i'd like to use as a generic
extension Model: Protocol {
  convenience init(foo:Int, bar:Int) {
    self.init()
    // do stuff
    println("it works \(foo)")
  }
}

// This is the final class using generics.
// Goal is to be able to use any of my model classes as a parameter
class Test<T: FakeRealmObject where T: Protocol> {
  func someMethod() {
    let instance = T(foo: 1, bar: 2)
  }
}
```

Giving this example, you can test it with :

```
let test = Test<Model>()
test.someMethod()
```

You will notice you get an error in xcode for the `let instance = T(foo: 1, bar: 2)` line

`extra argument 'foo' in call`

Depending on my trials, i also got

`Cannot find an initializer for type 'T' that accepts an argument list of type '(foo:Int, bar:Int)'`

Thing is, if you remove the subclassing to `NSObject` in the class `FakeRealmObject`, the error disappear and everything is working as expected.
Of course, with the real `Object` class from Realm you can't do that.

To be perfectly accurate, when digging into Realm, we can see `Object` definition :

`class Object : RLMObjectBase, Equatable, Printable`

and `RLMObjectBase` :

`class RLMObjectBase : NSObject`

I tried many things to find a solution, but nothing's working so far and i'm depending on Realm which of course i can't modify.

Am I doing a bad design? If yes, what is the right way to do it?
Is this a deeper problem with the code/compiler? I got a few segfaults while trying to find a solution, which is definitely not good.

Comment: Which Swift version? What is `Object` ?

Comment: My Xcode demands that `class Class` is declared as `final` – and then `let Init1 = T(foo: 1, bar: 2) ` does compile.

Comment: Swift 1.2 (i made an edit). `Object` is only here for the sake of the example, I could have write `Foobar`

Comment: the class `Class` is actually already declared as `final`, but that doesn't change the problem on my side.

Comment: Could you edit your question to add the `final` and to make it self-contained? – As I said, with `final class Class { }` the line `let Init1 = T(foo: 1, bar: 2)` *does* compile in my Xcode 6.4.

Comment: Well, i didn't expect my sample to compile, it was there only for the sake of the illustration, but as you said, actually it does. The only difference with the real code is that `Object` is actually an `Object` class from Realm. I don't know why nor how it's conflicting with the generic initialization, i will dig further then and will edit the question accordingly. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: I've totally reworked the question and the code, to provide a better understanding of the problem and a reproductible way to test it.